# LinkedIn API Company Data without Access Token?

Tags: api, linkedin-api

Currently, I am having a user go thru the OAuth process, wherein I get access to their profile, hence I know where they work, and I use the access token to get company information. Example:

```
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/162479/?oauth2_access_token=<token>
```

This works just fine. But what if I am working with another user that doesn't have linkedin, but they tell me they work at, say Apple Inc. How can I query LinkedIn when there is no access token?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem.

but i found out you cant use any linkedIN API calls wihtout authorization(access token).

Confirmed by linkedIN Employee:
http://developer.linkedin.com/forum/closed-get-people-company-without-authentication-not-possible

Alternativs?

- Building a scraper
- Save you own access token (expires in 60 days)